# Como manipular esses objetos com JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, array, objetos

Eu tenho os seguintes objetos:

```
{ letter: "A", num1: "1", num2: "2", num3: "3" }
{ letter: "B", num1: "3", num2: "2", num3: "1" }
{ letter: "C", num1: "2", num2: "3", num3: "1" }
```

Gostaria de transformar em um único objeto que recebe como atributo as letras e como valor um array/objeto de números:

```
var unicoObjeto = {
  A: { num1: "1", num2: "2", num3: "3" },
  B: { num1: "3", num2: "2", num3: "1" },
  C: { num1: "2", num2: "3", num3: "1" }
};
```

O que eu consegui até o momento foi:

```
var items = {};
var indice = [];
var data = [
    { letter: "A", num1: "1", num2: "2", num3: "3" },
    { letter: "B", num1: "3", num2: "2", num3: "1" },
    { letter: "C", num1: "2", num2: "3", num3: "1" }
];

$.each(data, function (i, val) {
    indice.push(val.letter);
});

Object.keys(data).forEach(key => {
    let newKey = indice[key];
    items[newKey] = items[key];
});

console.log(items);
```

Que apresenta o seguinte (não sei como passar os valores agora):

```
{ A: undefined, B: undefined, C: undefined }
```

Comment: Em JavaScript (não é necessário jQuery):

    function getUnicoObjeto(vetor) {
    const unicoObjeto = {};
    vetor.forEach(function (e) {
        const novoObjeto = {};
        const atributos = Object.keys(e).filter(a => a != "letter");
        atributos.forEach(a => novoObjeto[a] = e[a]);
        unicoObjeto[e.letter] = novoObjeto;
    });
    return unicoObjeto;
}

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Para cada elemento de `data` aplique uma função que adiciona a propriedade `items[val.letter]` o valor `val` e em seguida remova a letra com o operador [delete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) em `delete val.letter`

```js
var items = {};
var data = [
    { letter: "A", num1: "1", num2: "2", num3: "3" },
    { letter: "B", num1: "3", num2: "2", num3: "1" },
    { letter: "C", num1: "2", num2: "3", num3: "1" }
];

$.each(data, (i, val) => {    
    items[val.letter] = val; 
    delete val.letter;
});


console.log(items);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 12):

Você poderia usar métodos como o `reduce`, em conjunto com outros recursos do JavaScript.

A lógica é simples:

- A cada iteração, queremos adicionar ao objeto acumulador (`acc`) uma propriedade cuja chave será a propriedade `letter` e o valor será o restante do objeto.
- Então, capturamos a chave, depois removemos ela do objeto atual (utilizando o operador `delete`) e definimos a nova propriedade no objeto acumulador.

Para saber mais, consulte a documentação sobre o [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).

```js
const data = [
  { letter: "A", num1: "1", num2: "2", num3: "3" },
  { letter: "B", num1: "3", num2: "2", num3: "1" },
  { letter: "C", num1: "2", num2: "3", num3: "1" }
];

const myObj = data.reduce((acc, current) => {
  // Mantemos a chave armazenada em uma variável, para que não
  // a percamos depois de deletá-la do objeto atual.
  const key = current.letter;

  // Deletamos a propriedade `letter` do objeto, já que ela será a chave:
  delete current.letter;

  // Definimos uma nova propriedade no objeto `acc` com a chave
  // lendo a letra e o valor o restante do objeto.
  acc[key] = current;

  // Passamos para a próxima iteração:
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(myObj);
```

Se você quiser, pode inclusive usar os recursos mais modernos do JavaScript, como a função `Object.assign`:

```js
const data = [
  { letter: 'A', num1: '1', num2: '2', num3: '3' },
  { letter: 'B', num1: '3', num2: '2', num3: '1' },
  { letter: 'C', num1: '2', num2: '3', num3: '1' }
];

const myObj = data.reduce(
  (acc, { letter, ...current }) => Object.assign(acc, {
    [letter]: current
  }),
  {}
);

console.log(myObj);
```

Poderia também utilizar a [notação de espalhamento de objetos (`...`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Spread_in_object_literals), embora possa ser menos eficiente ao se recriar o objeto diversas vezes. [Saiba mais aqui.](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/477899/69296)

E se você quiser usar o `$.each` do jQuery, pode fazer assim:

```js
const data = [
  { letter: 'A', num1: '1', num2: '2', num3: '3' },
  { letter: 'B', num1: '3', num2: '2', num3: '1' },
  { letter: 'C', num1: '2', num2: '3', num3: '1' }
];

const myObj = {};

$.each(data, (index, current) => {
  const key = current.letter;
  delete current.letter;
  myObj[key] = current;
});

console.log(myObj);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Excelente resposta!

Answer (score 4):

Cria uma função construtora para popular os items do seu objeto.

```js
var items = {};
var indice = [];
var data = [
    { letter: "A", num1: "1", num2: "2", num3: "3" },
    { letter: "B", num1: "3", num2: "2", num3: "1" },
    { letter: "C", num1: "2", num2: "3", num3: "1" }
];

$.each(data, function (i, val) {
    indice.push(val.letter);
});

// Função Construtora
function ItemsLetter(num1, num2, num3) {
    this.num1 = num1;
    this.num2 = num2;
    this.num3 = num3;
}

data.forEach(function(element, key) {
    let newKey = element.letter;
    items[newKey] = new ItemsLetter(element.num1, element.num2, element.num3
    )
});

console.log(items);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Pelo que eu entendi você quer fazer uma matriz, das letras é isso?

```
var data = [
    { letter: "A", num1: "1", num2: "2", num3: "3" },
    { letter: "B", num1: "3", num2: "2", num3: "1" },
    { letter: "C", num1: "2", num2: "3", num3: "1" }
];

var collection = [];
for(var i in data) {
   collection[data[i].letter] = [data[i].num1, data[i].num2,  data[i].num3];
}

console.log(collection);
```

Ou em objeto:

```
 var collection = [];
    for(var i in data) {
       collection[data[i].letter] = {num1:data[i].num1, num2:data[i].num2,  num3: data[i].num3};
    }
```