# Qual é a diferença entre Object.assign e spread operator?

Tags: javascript, característica-linguagem, objetos, ecmascript-6

Qual é a diferença detalhada de se usar `Object.assign` e o spread operator (`...`) para o espalhamento de propriedades de objetos?

Por exemplo, ao editar um objeto para novos valores, é a mesma saída:

```js
const cursoNaDB = {
  abreviacao: "ES5",
  nome: "EcmaScript5",
  ano: "2009",
  categoria: "INICIANTE"
}

const cursoParaAlterarNaDB = {
  abreviacao: "ES6",
  nome: "EcmaScript6",
  ano: "2015",
  categoria: "AVANÇADO"
}

console.log(Object.assign(cursoNaDB, cursoParaAlterarNaDB));

console.log({ ...cursoNaDB, ...cursoParaAlterarNaDB });
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Existem algumas diferenças sutis:

### Diferença na definição de propriedades

A primeira delas é que `Object.assign` utiliza a operação interna [`[[Set]]`](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-set-o-p-v-throw) para definir as propriedades. A notação de espalhamento (*spread operator*) simplesmente irá definir as propriedades. Assim, `Object.assign` chamará os [*setters*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set), mas o *spread operator* não. Veja um exemplo:

```js
const target = {
  set foo(val) {
    console.log('Chamou o set:', val);
  }
};
const other = { foo: 123 };

// Object.assign chama o setter:
console.log(
  Object.assign(target, other)
);

console.log('---');

// Spread operador não chama o setter:
console.log(
  { ...target, ...other }
);
```

Note, no exemplo acima, que como o *spread operator* nem sequer chamou o *setter*, a propriedade `foo` foi definida como `123` no objeto resultante. Contudo, ao utilizarmos `Object.assign`, o valor que definimos para `foo` não fica persistido no objeto resultante, já que o *setter* não faz nada com ele (além de imprimi-lo no console).

Assim, pode-se afirmar que o `Object.assign` funciona de forma similar ao [operador de atribuição (`=`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#operador_atribuicao), que também executa a operação interna [`[[Set]]`](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-set-o-p-v-throw) (o que invoca os *setters*, se existirem). O *spread operator* funciona de modo mais similar ao [`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty), que não executa *setters*:

```js
const obj = {
  set foo(val) {
    console.log('Chamou o setter: ', val);
  }
};

// Object.assign se assemelha a isto:
obj.foo = 123;
console.log(obj); // { foo: undefined }

console.log('---');

// Spread operator se assemelha a isto:
Object.defineProperty(obj, 'foo', {
  value: 123
});
console.log(obj); // { foo: 123 }
```

### Possível diferença no construtor do objeto resultante

Uma outra diferença é que o protótipo e construtor do objeto resultante poderá ser diferente de `Object` ao utilizar `Object.assign`. Ao utilizarmos o *spread operator*, o construtor do objeto resultante é, sempre, `Object`:

```js
class DifferentThanObject {
  a = 1;
  b = 2;
}

const instance = new DifferentThanObject();
const other = { c: 3, d: 4 };

const obj1 = Object.assign(instance, other);
console.log(obj1.constructor.name); // DifferentThanObject

const obj2 = { ...instance, ...other };
console.log(obj2.constructor.name); // Object
```

Para entender, precisamos estar cientes da assinatura de `Object.assign`:

> ```
> Object.assign(target, ...sources)
> ```

A diferença de construtores se dá, então, já que `Object.assign` "copia" todas as propriedades enumeráveis de cada um dos objetos `source` (passados do segundo argumento para frente) para o destino (`target`, o primeiro argumento). Assim, o construtor do objeto resultante será sempre o mesmo do objeto `target`.

Conforme vimos no exemplo acima, como `instance` (passado como `target` para o `Object.assign`) é uma instância de `DifferentThanObject`, a saída também será uma instância de `DifferentThanObject`.

A [especificação da linguagem para `Object.assign`](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-object.assign) deixa isso excepcionalmente claro (referir ao link para o algoritmo completo):

> Perform ? Set(to, nextKey, propValue, true).

<sup>Sendo `to` o objeto que foi passado como `target`, `nextKey` a chave da propriedade a ser definida e `propValue` o valor desta.</sup>

Isso evidencia que um novo objeto nem chega a ser criado. Para cada propriedade dos objetos `source`, será executada a operação [`[[Set]]`](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-set-o-p-v-throw) no `target`. Ou seja, o mesmo objeto que entra como `target` é aquele que sai, só que com propriedades setadas a mais.

No entanto, sempre que utilizarmos o *spread operator* para fazer essa "transferência" de propriedades, o construtor do objeto resultante será `Object`. Isso acontece porque sempre criamos um novo objeto literal (que é, por definição, construído por `Object`):

```js
const literal = {};
console.log(literal.constructor.name); // Object
```

A diferença pode ser melhor entendida se tentarmos imitar o comportamento de `Object.assign` e do *spread operator* explicitamente:

```js
class DifferentThanObject {
  a = 1;
  b = 2;
}

const instance = new DifferentThanObject();
const other = { c: 3, d: 4 };

// ------- "Imitando" `Object.assign`:
// Object.assign(instance, other);

const resulting1 = instance;
resulting1.c = other.c;
resulting1.d = other.d;

console.log(resulting1);

// ------- "Imitando" spread operator:
// { ...instance, ...other };

const resulting2 = {};
Object.defineProperty(resulting2, 'a', { value: instance.a, enumerable: true });
Object.defineProperty(resulting2, 'b', { value: instance.b, enumerable: true });
Object.defineProperty(resulting2, 'c', { value: other.c, enumerable: true });
Object.defineProperty(resulting2, 'd', { value: other.d, enumerable: true });

console.log(resulting2);
```

Note que, ao utilizarmos o *spread operator*, somos "obrigados" a criar um novo objeto literal (com a notação `{}`) para que, sobre ele, as propriedades sejam espalhadas. O `Object.assign` irá simplesmente setar as propriedades a qualquer valor passado ao seu primeiro argumento.

Você pode passar um objeto vazio como `target` no `Object.assign` se quiser garantir que somente as propriedades próprias e enumeráveis serão transferidas, deixando de "transferir" o construtor e propriedades do protótipo do objeto `target`:

```js
class DifferentThanObject {
  // Métodos são anexados ao protótipo:
  method() {
    // noop
  }
  
  // Propriedades da instância:
  a = 1;
}

const instance = new DifferentThanObject();
const other = { b: 2 };

const resulting1 = { ...instance, ...other };
console.log(resulting1.constructor.name); // Object
console.log(typeof resulting1.method); // undefined //=> Métodos do protótipo NÃO são "transferidos".
console.log(resulting1); // { a: 1, b: 2 }

console.log('---');

const resulting2 = Object.assign(instance, other);
console.log(resulting2.constructor.name); // DifferentThanObject
console.log(typeof resulting2.method); // function //=> Métodos do protótipo são "transferidos".
console.log(resulting2); // { a: 1, b: 2 }

console.log('---');

//        Objeto literal "vazio" ↓↓
const resulting3 = Object.assign({}, instance, other);
console.log(resulting3.constructor.name); // Object
console.log(typeof resulting3.method); // undefined //=> Métodos do protótipo NÃO são "transferidos".
console.log(resulting3); // { a: 1, b: 2 }
```

Isso acontece porque, nesse último exemplo, `target` é um objeto literal (cujo construtor é `Object`) e, como vimos, o `Object.assign` resulta no próprio `target`, só que com as propriedades dos outros objetos (`sources`) setadas.

Vale a pena ler [Qual é a diferença entre criar um objeto a partir da forma literal ou a partir de uma função construtora?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/445960/69296) para entender melhor.

### Conclusão

No seu caso, como você não está lidando com *setters* e os objetos têm o mesmo construtor (`Object`, já que ambos foram criados de forma literal), não há nenhuma diferença real.

A única ressalva é que `Object.assign` é um pouco mais suportado que o *spread operator* para o espalhamento de propriedades de objetos. Isso porque `Object.assign` foi introduzido no ECMAScript 2015 (ES6), enquanto o *spread operator* só ganhou a habilidade de espalhar propriedades de objetos no ECMAScript 2018.

Comment: Legal, por isso que o `Object.assign` funciona bem com o Vue.

Comment: Ótima resposta! perfeitamente descrita a questão da instância do objeto e sobre o acionamento do setter. Me ajudou muito