# Objetos com campos de nomes iguais utilizando a notação de espalhamento (spread operator)

Tags: javascript, característica-linguagem, objetos

Considerando dois objetos (user e unidade):

```js
var user = {
    nome: 'Nome aqui',
    idade: 45
};

var unidade = {
    nome: 'Nome da unidade',
    idade: 22
};


// Spread Operador
var dadosGerais = {
    ...user,
    ...unidade
};

console.log(dadosGerais);
```

O resultado de saída é o seguinte:

[image: Saída do código anterior no console das ferramentas de desenvolvedor do Google Chrome]

Não é possível utilizar o *spread* quando os nomes dos campos são iguais, no caso, `nome` e `idade` que são repetidos em user e unidade?

Caso seja possível, como deve ser feito?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não é que não pode usar a notação de espalhamento em objetos que contenham nomes de propriedades iguais. Pode e está, de fato, sendo feito.

O problema é que objetos não podem ter duas propriedades com o mesmo nome. Se isso ocorrer, somente a última propriedade definida com o nome repetido será considerada. A anterior será sobrescrita silenciosamente. Vejamos:

```js
const obj = {
  name: 'Old',
  age: 50,
  name: 'Foo'
};

console.log(obj);
console.log(obj.name); // Foo
```

Note que a propriedade `name` foi definida duas vezes. No entanto, somente a última, definida com valor `'Foo'` permaneceu.

Quando você utiliza a notação de espalhamento, as propriedades da cada objeto são **definidas** no objeto resultante (explico melhor sobre isso [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/477899/69296)) e, desse modo, se existirem propriedades com mesmo nome, somente a última será mantida.

Se você precisar criar um novo objeto com todos os valores, de modo que não sejam perdidos, deverá utilizar nomes diferentes. Uma alternativa:

```js
const user = {
  nome: 'Nome aqui',
  idade: 45
};

const unidade = {
  nome: 'Nome da unidade',
  idade: 22
};

const result = {
  ...user,
  unidade
};

console.log(result);
```