# É possível utilizar Object.assign para atribuir propriedades ao this no JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, orientação-a-objetos, objetos

Estou aprendendo sobre objetos agora e gostaria de saber se é possível usar `Object.assign` para atribuir todas as propriedades ao `this` de uma classe no JavaScript.

Exemplo:

```
class Foo {
  name;
  email;
  phone;

  constructor(name, email, phone) {
    this.name = name;
    this.email = email;
    this.phone = phone;
  }

  method() {
    console.log(this.name, this.email, this.phone);
  }
}
```

Transformar o trecho de código acima para a solução abaixo:

```
class Foo {
  name;
  email;
  phone;

  constructor(name, email, phone) {
    Object.assign(this, name, email, phone);
  }

  method() {
    console.log(this.name, this.email, this.phone);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sim. Conforme expliquei [nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/477899/69296), o `Object.assign` utiliza a operação interna [`[[Set]]`](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-set-o-p-v-throw) para setar as propriedades dos objetos passados do segundo argumento em diante no objeto passado como primeiro argumento. Desse modo, é a mesma coisa de atribuir as propriedades explicitamente utilizando o operador de atribuição (`=`), que também utiliza a operação `[[Set]]`.

No entanto, note que você não está passando objetos do segundo argumento em diante, mas sim valores primitivos (provavelmente strings):

> ```
> Object.assign(this, name, email, phone);
> //                  ↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑
> //                  Devem ser objetos.
> ```

Observe que `name`, `email` e `phone` são (provavelmente) strings, e não objetos. Portanto, você deve utilizar assim:

```
//                  ↓                    ↓
Object.assign(this, { name, email, phone });
```

Note que acima foi utilizada a [notação abreviada de nomes de propriedades](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015) para se criar o objeto literal. Ela foi introduzida no ECMAScript 2015 (ES6).

Exemplo:

```js
class Foo {
  constructor(name, email, phone) {
    Object.assign(this, { name, email, phone });
  }

  method() {
    console.log(this.name, this.email, this.phone);
  }
}

const inst = new Foo('a', 'b', 'c');
inst.method(); // a b c
```

---

<sup>Note que eu adicionei ponto e vírgula no código. Pode parecer "frescura" e sei que o JavaScript "aceita" o código sem ponto e vírgula e "funciona", mas isso evita algumas situações bizarras que podem ocorrer se você não os usar, como [esta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1169596) e [esta](/q/432960) (veja mais sobre isso [aqui](/q/3341)).</sup>

<sup>Também removi os inicializadores de propriedade no começo da classe já que eles não estavam fazendo nada ali, uma vez que as propriedades já serão inicializadas no construtor.</sup>

Comment: Nossa, uma verdadeira aula!!! Cara, muito obrigado pela explicação, eu procurei em outros sites, artigos e até mesmo vídeos e não encontrei nada tão objetivo e tão didático quanto a sua resposta!! muito obrigado mesmo.