# Como colocar tipagem no retorno do Object.keys sendo os tipos as keys do Objeto ou da interface?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuex

Tenho o seguinte

Interface

```
interface UserState {
  id: string;
  isDeleted: boolean;
  deletedAt: null | string;
  name: string;
  email: string;
  picture: string;
}
```

Objeto

```
const state: UserState  = {
  id: '',
  name: '',
  email: '',
  deletedAt: null,
  isDeleted: false,
  picture: ''
}
```

Estou usando vuex como lib de estado central e preciso criar uma método (mutation) que recebe um payload (`objeto: Partial<UserState>`) e atualiza o state (`objeto: UserState`)

Tentativa com spread operator

```
// mutation    
SET_INFO (state: UserState, payload: Partial<UserState>) {
      state = {...state, ...payload}
}
```

O exemplo acima não é funcional pois desse jeito o vuex não é capaz de atuar com reatividade, Talvez por que isso sobrescreve o state por inteiro.

Tentativa com object.keys

```
  SET_INFO (state: UserState, payload: Partial<UserState>) {
    type UserStateKeys = keyof UserState

    const keyNames: UserStateKeys[] = Object.keys(state) as UserStateKeys[]
    keyNames.forEach((keyName) => {
        if (payload[keyName]) { 
          state[keyName] = payload[keyName]
        }
    })
  }
```

Esse com Javascript puro é funcional, porém em typescript há o seguinte impeditivo

> Type 'string | boolean | null | undefined' is not assignable to type
> 'never'.   Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'never'.ts(2322)
> (parameter) keyName: keyof UserState

Pelo o que eu entendi da mensagem, quando uso o `keyName` como index no `payload`, não é possível determina com precisão  o tipo de valor retornado para `state[keyName]`.

Linha da mensagem de erro
`state[keyName] = payload[keyName]`

Tanto que se eu fizer isso aqui é aceito
`state.email = payload[keyName] as string`

Existe alguma jeito de eu fazer essa tipagem?

Comment: Ao invés de utilizar o _spread operator_ para fazer o _merge_ das propriedades, utilize a função `Object.assign`, que tem semântica de `set` (o que funciona para o jeito que o Vuex trata o estado). Veja mais em [Qual é a diferença entre Object.assign e spread operator?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/477895/69296).

Comment: Talvez valha a pena [edit] a pergunta para torná-la um pouco mais ampla (a parte do Vue não tem muito a ver com o erro que você, de fato, está tendo com o TypeScript).

Comment: Boa, com concordo com o Vue não ter relação com o problema da tipagem. Mas eu o coloquei para contextualizar onde o código será executado, na expectativa de que alguém trouxesse um uma solução de acordo com  essa situação na mutation do vuex.

Answer (score 3):

Neste caso o compilador do typescript não consegue inferir se os tipos são os mesmos, já que uma união de diferentes tipos não possui ordem, a solução é deixar um pouco da tipagem de lado neste caso.

```
  SET_INFO (state: UserState, payload: Partial<UserState>) {
    const keyNames = Object.keys(state)
    keyNames.forEach((keyName) => {
        if (payload[keyName]) { 
          state[keyName] = payload[keyName]
        }
    })
  }
```

Comment: Só para constar que, em relação ao TypeScript, [há uma discussão sobre isso no GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/31663).

Comment: Na verdade este issue não está relacionado a este problema, neste caso está mais relacionado com as limitações do typescript. O never é utilizado quando você sabe que algo jamais irá ocorrer e neste caso o typescript está correto em assumir isso, pois ele não consegue relacionar o bloco if com o assignment que está ocorrendo.

Comment: Sim, @AyAyEm, exatamente. A limitação do TypeScript (que é discutida na issue em questão) leva a problemas como este.

Comment: @AyAyEm Nesse caso não consigo remover a tipagem nesse método, ele pertence a um objeto que infere tipos.

Comment: Tinha esquecido de remover um cast no exemplo, perdão.

Comment: @AyAyEm `const mutations: MutationTree<UserState> = {SET_INFO(state, paylod) {...} }`